# MySQLのパフォーマンスチューニング

Tags: mysql

お世話になります。
mysqlのパフォーマンス・チューニングというか全般的な設定方法でいくつか経験者の方のご意見伺いたいのですが、
現在普通にmysqlを使っていてストンと落ちた感じになって、利用しているphp側でホワイトアウトした状態になることが度々あります。当初はAWSのEC2などの最も小さいインスタンスでmysqlを使ったときに頻発しまして、このたびはSakuraの専用サーバーでも時々起きている感じです。
http://open-groove.net/mysql/crash-recovery-innodb-log/
ここらあたりの調整をしてみたり、いろいろやっているのですが、原因が特定できていません。
ものすごい強烈なSQL文が走るというわけではありませんが、数万件のそこそこのデータをいろいろやりくりしている感じです。
何かしらの一般的なデバック方法やチューニングの方法などアイディアいただくことできるでしょうか。
私自身もWordpressでちょこちょこmysqlを使ったり、スクラッチで書いたPHPでmysqlつないで云々ということをやっていて、実践的なパフォーマンス・チューニングというのをやったことがないです。（これをパフォーマンス・チューニングで何とかなるものなのかもちょっとわからない次第です。）
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: MySQL のバージョン、MySQL サーバをインストールしている OS 等を開示すると、より回答が得られやすくなると思います。ちなみにエラーログなどは見ましたか？ Linux 等なら /etc/my.cnf の `[mysql]` セクションに `datadir=` といった感じで書かれていると思います。また、同様に実行時エラーログの設定は `[mysqld]` セクションに `log-error=` で設定できます。役立ちそうな記事はこちらも参照してください[誰も教えてくれなかったMySQLの障害解析方法 | Qiita](http://qiita.com/muran001/items/14f19959d4723ffc29cc)

Comment: サーバやMySQLの運用についてどれだけの知識があるのか、自分でどこまで調べていてその結果はどうだったのか、が具体的でないので回答がしにくい質問です。何を調べていいかもわからないのであればQ&Aでの解決は困難なので、まず書籍等で勉強されるか、ディスカッション形式でアドバイスをしてもらえる他のサイトを使うか、専門知識をお金で買うかのどれかをお勧めします。